# How to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x \sin x}{x^2+a^2}dx=\pi e^{-a}$ using residue theory.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

> I want to compute the following:
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x \sin x}{x^2+a^2}dx=\pi e^{-a}$$

so I chose the following function $f(z)=\frac{-ize^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}$ and I decided to integrate over the real line and semicircle ($C$), but then when I try to bound over the semicircle I've got this:

$$\left\lvert \int _{C}f(z)dz \right\rvert \le \pi R· \frac{R}{R^2+a^2}$$

and that thing doesn't go to zero, then I tried to do this using now a square as a contour but the integral doesn't seem very friendly there, So Can someone help me with this issue please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: apply jordans lemma

Comment: What is that? :)

Comment: Six characters: G O O G L E

Comment: Sorry :),let me check it, just a second :)

Comment: Good, so with that bound this issue is straight foward isn't ?

Comment: Exactly, it is mad for situations like that

Comment: And with out that inequality, Is there a way?

Comment: u could argue heuristically that the oscillations improve the convergences of the integral because it will lead to cancellations. otherwise, i'm sure u can give other rigorous proofs but i don't have one at the top of my head

Comment: ahhh integration by parts should also work for this particular example

Comment: Well, but the thing is not to use integration right ? I mean, I could be hard to do :)

Comment: it is not hard in this particular example use finite integration limits $\pm R$ then set $x\sin(x)=u',(a^2+x^2)^{-1}=v$  and i.b.p the resulting integral is  convergent for $R\rightarrow\infty$ and the boundary term vanishs

Comment: So with that you are computing the integral with out residues right?

Comment: No im only show convergence with out using jordans lemma

Comment: So can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: what else do u want to know? show convergence in one of the ways i told u and afterwards evaluate the integral using residues. it is quiet standard

Comment: From Jordan's Lemma the upper bound should be $\frac{\pi R}{R^2-a^2}$ so you have one $R$ too many

Answer (score 1):

On the semicircular contour $C_{R}(\theta)=Re^{i\theta}$ for $0 \le \theta\le \pi$, and $R > |a|$,
$$
     \left|\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}\right| \le \frac{Re^{-R\sin\theta}}{R^2-|a|^2} 
$$
Therefore, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem,
$$
       \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left|\int_{C_{R}}\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}dz\right|
        \le \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{Re^{-R\sin\theta}}{R^2-|a|^2}Rd\theta =0.
$$